# Adding RAM memory to my 2011 iMac

Tags: imac, memory

I am adding more RAM memory to my 2011 21-inch iMac. It currently has two 2 GB memory cards. Can I leave those two cards in place and simply add two new 4 GB memory cards, or do I need to remove the existing cards? Is it OK to mix 2 GB and 4 GB memory cards, provided I stay under Apple's 16 GB limit?

Comment: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2428+RAM+Replacement/5660

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. RAM can be mismatched and combined in every way. However, 2x2GB will not be as fast as 1x4GB memory. That being said, it shouldn't really matter that much.